# Suppress error in shell script

Tags: scripting

I want to run a script like below:

```
for i in `cat`;do 
result=command $i |awk '{print $2}'  ## it may give us the exact anwer or error like "command not found"
echo "$i - $result"  
done
```

for every `$i`, I want to print:

```
$i - $result    # if success
$i - NO RESULT  # if I got command not found error
```

Comment: This is basic error handling in shells like bash and zsh. You should probably read the documentation on the shell in which you're going to be writing this script. `man bash` or `man zsh` should get you started in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

```
while read -r cmd; do
    result=$( command $cmd 2>/dev/null || echo "Just a boring error" )
    printf '%s\t- %s\n' "$cmd" "$result"
done
```

Read will read from the standard input of the shell, line by line.  If you try to use `for cmd in $(cat)`, the `cat` process will need to exit before any part of the loop is run.  With the above loop, each iteration is done as the lines arrive on standard input.

The `result` variable will get the output of the command substitution.  The command substitution will return the output of the command, or the `echo` if the command in `$cmd` exited with a non-zero exit status.